# IE9 not printing table body (tbody) when it takes more than one page

Tags: css, html, printing, html-table, internet-explorer-9

I have an html5 webpage with a data table that is printed correctly on every platform, except for IE9.

Error details:

- When the table content fits in one page, the table is printed
  correctly.
- The table header is always printed correctly.

I already validated the html/CSS code, by the way.

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution the hard way.

Apparently IE9 doesn't like when any parent element has the `float: left` style, which is very common to find in any CSS grid system (*Bootstrap*, *Foundation*, *Gumby*, etc).

The only way I was able to make it work, was enforcing `float: none` for all the parent elements/containers of the `table`.

More info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1f0d0898-e613-4421-83d2-a9f57ab8bba4/ie9-standards-mode-not-printing-table-body-tbody-when-it-spans-pages